# Bash timeout with piped input

Tags: bash, timeout, pipe, tar

There is a command (say $run_command), which has to be killed after timeout. The solution is quite simple - I can just use *timeout* from coreutils or *timeout3* from other stackoverflow topics. But my command receives it's stdin from untar pipe smth like this

```
tar -xO -f "$1" | /usr/bin/time -f "%e" --output=$time_output -- $run_command
```

Where *$run-command* is my command, which execution time has also be measured (using the *time* utility).

So, the question is what is the best way to avoid including untarring time in the *timeout* utility?

Comment: "There is a script" is unclear.  Is it this calling script or $run_command which needs to be killed after the timeout?

Comment: No, it's $run_command which needs to be killed. Thanks, i'll edit the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In very simple form, you can kill the calling script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

( sleep $timeout_period && kill $$ ) &

tar -xO -f "$1" | ...
```

Of course, this is only an example; you'll want to provide some insurance that $$ is still the same script when `kill` runs.

This will of course kill the whole script, including `time` (which will be $timeout_period if the script was killed).

**UPDATE #1**:

Example using a tempfile.

```
tmpfile=$(/usr/bin/mktemp /tmp/temp.XXXXX)

tar -xO -f "$1" > $tmpfile
trap "rm -f $tmpfile" 0 1 2 3 15

/usr/bin/time -f "%e" --output=$time_output -- $run_command < $tmpfile
```

Note that this is still subject to error due to the speed/performance of your filesystem.

**UPDATE #2**:

This adds the timeout function in addition to exempting `tar` time:

```
(
  tmpfile=$(/usr/bin/mktemp /tmp/temp.XXXXX)
  tar -xO -f "$1" > $tmpfile
  trap "rm -f $tmpfile" 0 1 2 3 15
  /usr/bin/time -f "%e" --output=$time_output -- $run_command < $tmpfile
) &

pid=$!

( sleep $timeout_period && kill $pid ) &

wait %1
```

The same potential issue in the first script segment exists; you'll want to provide insurance that $$ is still what you think it before you kill it.  Also, the signal will be sent to the shell wrapper, not directly to your command.  You'll have to test whether signals get passed through to your command as expected.

Note also that this backgrounds the timeout/kill.  The "wait" tells the script to wait until  the first background process is finished, so *either* your command finishes by itself *or* it gets killed by the timeout ... and then the script proceeds to anything after the `wait`.  If the command finishes by itself, then that's where you run into potential issues with $pid being recycled for another process.  Solving that is left as an exercise for the reader.  :-)

Comment: In this example _tar_ execution time will also be present in the $timeout_period. It's the situation I want to avoid.

Comment: Of course, I wrote this before you clarified what you wanted killed.  If you want to completely exclude tar's effect on your time, you need to store data in a temporary file.  I'll update...

Comment: I clarified what i wanted to be killed in the topic before your answer. But still, thanks. And, also, why do you need _trap_? Temporary file is supposed to disappear after parent process will finish, isn't it?

Comment: In a shell script? Something has to remove a temporary file. What would remove it, if not the trap? Also, your question was edited to clarify what you wanted to kill four hours after the initial answer.

Comment: @ghoti Thanks for so detailed answer. I'll mark your's as an answer. About clarifying what to be killed - my bad, sorry. I just said it unclear.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for in this example is a temporary file, not a pipeline. In most cases, you want to execute a pipeline in parallel. In your case (profiling) and also when preceding commands should succeed before executing later commands, a sequential operation is desirable. I recommend using `mktemp` for this effect. I don't know of a way to use FIFOs either via process substitution or with `mkfifo` for this example, as `$run_command` is always dependent on the output of `tar`.

Comment: I have usually used `tempfile` for this purpose, though I don't really know why.  Is `mktemp` better?

Comment: You propose to untar contents of $1 into tempfile and then use smth like this `/usr/bin/time -f "%e" --output=$time_output -- $run_command < $tempfile_name` ?

Comment: Yes, I'd first use `mktemp` to get a safe file to untar to, then execute `$run_command` as you say.

Comment: @StephenNiedzielski:  +1.  Well, who knew?  For future readers' reference, Russ Allbery's thoughts on the topic are found at http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2006/12/msg00040.html .  (Almost anything Mr. Allbery writes, on almost any topic, is worth reading, incidentally.)